# Cannot access session or req.user in getServerSideProps in nextjs

Tags: node.js, session, passport.js, next.js

I need to fetch data based on a `userId` but using SSR and utilizing the SSR features, how can I access the `userId` obtained after the login is successful in the SSR function `getServerSideProps` provided by NextJS. I have the following implementation right now.

User is redirected to `pages/index.js` once he logs in,
This is `pages/index.js`

```
import { useUser } from '../libs/hooks';
import { client } from '../middlewares/database';
import Home from './Home';
import Landing from './Landing';

const App = ({ data }) => {
  
    const [user] = useUser();
    /* I have the user details here and I have a hook for getting user details,
but this is the client-side */
    return user?<Home data={data} />:<Landing />
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const userId = context.req.headers.userId;
    // userId is undefined here, I need the userId here
    if (!client.isConnected()) await client.connect();

    const db = client.db(process.env.DB_NAME);
    const response = await db.collection("data").find({ userId });
    
    return { props: { data: response } }
}

export default App;
```

I am using `passport.js` and `next-session` to authenticate the user and create a session `sid` which is available in all functions.  If I can store the `userId` in the session that would help as well.

This is my server middleware.

```
import nextConnect from "next-connect";
import passport from "../libs/passport";
import database from "./database";
import session from "./session";

const middleware = nextConnect();

middleware
  .use(database)
  .use(session)
  .use(passport.initialize())
  .use(passport.session());

export default middleware;
```

And this is how the login auth file looks;
`auth.js`

```
import nextConnect from 'next-connect';
import { session } from 'next-session';
import { extractUser } from '../../libs/api-helpers';
import passport from '../../libs/passport';
import middleware from '../../middlewares/middleware';

const handler = nextConnect();
handler.use(middleware);

handler.post(passport.authenticate('local'), async (req, res) => {

  res.json({ user: extractUser(req) });
});
```

I can either use the cookie approach or the session approach. How do I achieve that here in this scenario?

Comment: I set up a cookie on the client-side and using that to access the uid. I used `js-cookie` to achieve this.

Comment: Be sure to use apply (https://github.com/hoangvvo/next-connect#applyreq-res) in getServerSideProps

Answer (score 3):

`someMiddlewares.apply` has been deprecated. Please use `someMiddlewares.run`

```
await someMiddleswares.run(req, res)
```

See https://github.com/hoangvvo/next-connect/tree/21c9c73fe3746e66033fd51e2aa01d479e267ad6#runreq-res

Answer (score 2):

Define and export your middlewares:

```
import nextConnect from 'next-connect'

const middleware = nextConnect()

middleware.use(session)
middleware.use(passport.initialize())
middleware.use(passport.session())

export default middleware
```

Use the nextConnect `apply` method to apply all middlewares:

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ req, res }) {
  await middlewares.apply(req, res)
  console.log(req.user._id) // the user is available now!
```